# How to use Postgresql functions on Microsoft report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, microsoft-reporting

I am working on c# application with postgresql database. I used Microsoft report for reporting and everything is fine if I create report using table or view but could not use postgres function on report. Please help.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Many Microsoft products don't offer as much support for databases other than MS SQL. I wouldn't be surprised if this was a case where if you use ODBC to talk to DB you get fewer features than if you use the direct MS-SQL interface.